# Is it possible to communicate between Cordova and Native Android Via Socket Connection?

Tags: android, cordova, sockets

I am building a VoIP mobile app, using ionic and Cordova for the presentation layer, and Pjsip for SIP layer, but we are stuck at communication level between the two layers, Javascript and Android Java, I am not looking for using JavascriptInterface in the Cordova WebView, I want to use Socket Connection between Javascript and Android Java.

Things i looked at so far:

[ServerSocker](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html) I thought, I can use this as the server, and make Javascript in the Cordova WebView receives it's sockets.

[Native Socket IO Client](http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/) This is a Socket.IO Client for Android, if i can use this, I have to establish a Socket.IO server in Cordova WebView

Comment: Yes.  You can use network sockets if both ends are in packages with Internet permission and unix (local) sockets even if they are not.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Please can your recommend any libraries to use for both Java Android and Cordova Javascript ?

Comment: Library recommendation questions get closed as off topic - but you should not need anything beyond the respective SDK's.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add a comment but I can only add answer!  Since I have similar requirement.  Now I can use Signalr client socket in JavaScript running on an android or iPhone, or running on a desktop browser(with the html file hosted in www.a.com), to connect to the Signalr Websocket Server written by C# hosted in www.b.com    the client and Server can 'talk' to each other, however two clients cannot talk to each other without going through the Server.  Am I asking the same question?